# Dplyr, mutate with standard evaluation and vectors of column names as arguments

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following function, which I'd like to pass to `mutate` with standard evaluation. However, I couldn't figure how to build a formula from it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

# Define custom function
.dist <- function(x, y) {
  d <- sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))
  return(d)
}

# NSE example
iris %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(newVar = .dist(c(Petal.Width, Petal.Length), c(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length))) %>%
  tbl_df()

# SE attempt
iris %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_(newVar = interp(~.dist(x, y),
                          x = c(as.name('Petal.Width'), as.name('Petal.Length')),
                          y = c(as.name('Sepal.Width'), as.name('Sepal.Length')))) %>%
  tbl_df()
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear. Take an example: if you have Petal.Width=5, Petal.length=4, Sepal.width=3, Sepal.length=2, what result do you expect? I think the problem is that you haven't formulated what you want correctly, nothing to do with SE or NSE :)

Comment: Fyi, it has to do with your function definition; it works if you use for example `mutate_(newVar = interp(~.dist(x, y), x = as.name('Petal.Width'), y = as.name('Sepal.Width')))`

Comment: Seems to me that you want to create 2 variables, in which case you have to create 2 variables with your `mutate`.

Comment: @antoine-sac the `.dist()` function computes the euclidean distance between two numeric vectors. It's kind of meaningless in the present example since it's a dummy example. I'm not really interested in the euclidean distance between sepals and petals ;)

Comment: @antoine-sac To answer your question, your suggested single row example would result in the following call `.dist(c(5, 4), c(3,2))` , and return 2.82. And that's precisely what I'm after. It's actually not even that meaningless: it's the distance between sepals and petals, considering two of their attributes (width and length)